# Double underline under h1 in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to have my h1 have two borders under it. One that is thick and just the width of the text, and a second that is thinner and the width of the entire container.

Like this:

[image]

How can I do this with CSS?

I've tried quite a few things, and it seems like it'd be easy, but I can't figure it out! I also can't find any other forums or posts like this.

Answer (score 6):

If you can change your HTML to this:

```
<h1><span>Advertiser Name &mdash; Manage Campaigns</span></h1>
```

Then you can use this CSS:

```
h1 {border-bottom:2px solid black; padding-bttom:5px}
h1>span {border-bottom:5px solid black}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Gh2ks/)

Comment: Wow, thanks that was easy. The trouble I was having was making the first one not the full width. I don't even know why yours works, is it because a <span> tag doesn't fill its container or something?

Comment: That is correct. `<span>` elements are inline, so they only take up the width they need :)

Comment: Be aware that it is invalid HTML to have a `<div>` inside an `<h1>` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have two nested `<div>`s (or `<span>` or `<h1>` depending on the context) - one with the thick border and one with the thin border.